# Rotate an image using UISlider?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is there any way by which I can rotate an Image according to value of UISlider? I know rotation can be performed easily using Gestures but I have to perform it using UISLider.

Comment: Of course it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just UIRotateGesture which i dont wana use..:p..can u tell me where to start from?? I am new to development.

Comment: You should learn about two topics: 1. How to rotate UIViews, 2. How to use UISlider. To learn to understand the line of code in the answer of @AliSoftware below would be a good start.

Comment: yes thanku i got it...i was doing little differnt which was causing some delay in transforamtion.. anyways thnku..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI / slider.maximumValue);
```